# Calculate last letter in social security number

Tags: java

The code's purpose is to solve the last digit in a Swedish identity number and it doesn't seem to work. The algorithm is described here: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_%28Sweden%29#Checksum)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pers5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int k0=0,k1=0,k2=0,k3=0,k4=0,k5=0,k6=0,k7=0,k8=0;

    System.out.print("Skriv in ett personnummer: ");
    String indata = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
        int nummer=indata.charAt(i) -48;
            System.out.print(indata.charAt(i)+ " ");
            System.out.println(indata.charAt(i));


    int tal0 = indata.charAt(0);
    int tal1 = indata.charAt(1);
    int tal2 = indata.charAt(2);
    int tal3 = indata.charAt(3);
    int tal4 = indata.charAt(4);
    int tal5 = indata.charAt(5);
    int tal6 = indata.charAt(6);
    int tal7 = indata.charAt(7);
    int tal8 = indata.charAt(8);

    k0=tal0*2;
    k1=tal1;
    k2=tal2*2;
    k3=tal3;
    k4=tal4*2;
    k5=tal5;
    k6=tal6*2;
    k7=tal7;
    k8=tal8*2;
```

Here is the part that solves the last number:

```
    int sum = 0;
    while (k0 != 0) {
      sum += k0 % 10;
      k0 /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of digits: " + sum);}
}
```

Now it's obviously only supposed to solve the sum of k0 but that is all I need help with.

Comment: Can you please explain, in words (or via a link), how the last digit is supposed to be calculated? Some example input and output values would help.

Comment: What do you exactly want?

Comment: if i write in for example "941204546" then its supposed to write out the digit sum of 18 (9*2) When i write in "941204546" then i get "6" back instead of "9" as its supposed to write

Comment: @Marc - that doesn't answer the question.  You need to explain the algorithm rather than provide a (single) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guessed from you profile that you are talking about Swedish personal identity number.

Firstly, there is an error with `talX` variables. You forgot to substract `48` (or parse characters in some other way to get int value).

To respond to your question - you should delete all the:

```
int sum = 0;
while (k0 != 0) {
  sum += k0 % 10;
  k0 /= 10;
}
```

That will work just fine for the first digit:

`System.out.println("Sum of digits: " + (k0%10 + k0/10))`

That is what you asked about, but to solve the whole problem I suggest you to refactor your code. Variables like `k0`, `k1`, ... will not be easy to iterate over. Try to create an array (or even count next digits sums in `for (int i=0; i<9; i++)` loop).

For example:

```
for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
    int nummer = indata.charAt(i) - 48;
    int multiplied = nummer*((i+1)%2)+1); // it will multiply by 2 or 1 (depending on digit position)
    int sum = multiplied%10 + multiplied/10 // sum of digits
    System.out.println("The sum for " + i + " digit is: " + sum);
```

Of course you can stay with your `k0`, `k1`, ... but your code will be extremely long and complicated.

Comment: But now i need to add the digit sum of all the numbers. How would i do that?

Comment: That's pretty easy. Just use another variable, eg. `wholeSum` and in each iteration `wholeSum+=sum`

Comment: can you describe to me how "int multiplied = nummer*((i+1)%2)+1);" works?

Comment: @Marc `(i+1)%2` is equal `1` for even `i` and `0` for odd `i`, by adding `1` to that you will get `2` and `1`. That is the same which you have done that way: `k0=tal0*2;`, `k1=tal1*1;`, `k2=tal2*2;`... but in a loop - `2`/`1` is chosen automatically depending on the position `i` of digit in ID number. Note that first digit is at `i==0`